# Coherence on regular vs irregular verb spelling

Tags: irregular-verbs

I have been confused by this for quite some time. I have always used *learnt* as past forms of the verb *learn*. However, I have always used the regular spelling of the other verbs which follow the same pattern (dream, spoil, spell...).

My question is: If I choose to use the irregular spelling on *learn*, should I also use that spelling on the other verbs for consistency? (Or vice-versa).

Comment: You are free to do whatever you like in this regard. There are no consistency police. Native English speakers are all over the map on this, as on other things.

Comment: Which one is "irregular" spelling? To me, *dreamt* is the regular spelling, that is, the regular past tense whereas, *dreamed* is some weird alternative. On the other hand, authors a 100 or so years ago would use *lighted* rather than *lit*. It might be best to choose a decent dictionary and stick with what it lists as the first variant. *Learnt* is not at all American English, so that's another factor.

Answer (score -1):

Most native speakers will use *-ed* rather than *-t* for the majority of past-tense verbs. Using *-t* isn't wrong but I think it would sound odd to a lot of people. *Lit* and *dreamt* as mentioned in Clare's comment are a couple of exceptions (though I suspect that *lit* is much more commonly used than *dreamt*).

Using *-t* can also cause problems when it transforms the word into one with another meaning such as *smell* to *smelt* rather than *smelled*.

Comment: The fact that "smelt" happens to look the same as another word is not really a problem practically speaking.